# My SQL Table Partitions

Tags: mysql, sql, database-partitioning

- Example : I create a table with 1000 Data .
- I Partition this table

  ```
   alter table rnds add primary key (id) partition by HASH(id) partitions 200;
  ```
- I check in mysql data directory and found it create 5 part

`rnds#P#p0.ibd , rnds#P#p1.ibd , rnds#P#p2.ibd , rnds#P#p3.ibd , rnds#P#p4.ibd`

- After i insert another `1000 row` in this table and it insert successfully .
- My Questions is that why not new part are create for new `1000 data`.
- After create a table partition how the table manage new data .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want create 5 partitions you should use:

```
alter table rnds partition by HASH(id) partitions 5;
```

This command will create 5 partitions and new rows will be added to them based on `ID`. New partitions are not created automatically. You can add new partition using `ADD PARTITION` command.

See [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table-partition-operations.html) for details.

Comment: Ok now i understand . think i create a table rnds with 5 partitions , after i want to add another partitions , please write this command.  I have a table 2.7 Million row , will i get benifit if i make partition on this table

Comment: 2.7 million rows is not a big number. So you rather don't need partitioning at all.

Comment: sorry its 20.7 Million Data